# Can I enter the Schengen area if my visa period is valid before the 180 day rule

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

My new visa is valid for 90 days within 12-10-2018 to 12-10-2019. My last visit ended on 30-07-2018 and I plan to enter again at 23-10-2018. Will border control in the Netherlands deny entry because of the 180 days rule, even if the visa is valid?

The linked answer explains about the base of the rule. To rephrase my question: Will border control check the last stay or will they allow entry based on the visa validity?

Both the last stay and the intended stay are 90 days.

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not answer your question, please edit your question to explain why.  In order to answer your question, though, we would also need to know how many days you were present in the Schengen area during your last visit and how many days you plan to spend there when you enter on 23 October.

Comment: Is there any reason why they should allow you to violate the rules? If they did it would make a farce of the rules. The validity of the visa does not mean the ancillary rules should be overlooked. That would b akin to e saying if I have a valid visa and I show up at the border and tell them I plan to work illegally, they should allow me in because my visa is valid.

Comment: I just think it makes more sense if they consider the rules when giving the new validity dates. Instead of having the visa valid from 12-10-18 it should have been from 29-10-18 to avoid confusion with the 90 day rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have a new visa does not change the application of the 90/180 rule.  Since your previous stay in the Schengen area was 90 days long, the border officer should refuse entry unless at least 90 days have passed since you left.

That is, since you left on 30 July after a 90-day stay, the first day on which you may re-enter is 29 October.  I determined the date with the official [Schengen calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en) (the entry date for a 90-day stay ending on 30 July is 2 May).

The applicability of the 90/180 rule across different visas follows from Article 6 of the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407), which specifies "the 180-day period preceding each day of stay" without reference to whether the previous stay was authorized by the same visa as the current stay.